# Athena returning GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Multiple entries with same key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

I am using UNLOAD to write query results into S3 using Athena. I have the tables partitioned by month and day. I ran into an issue today (November 11th) when trying to partition using different keys but the values are the same. Here is the query:

```
unload(
        select name,
            '11' as start_month,
            '11' as start_day
        from employees
        limit 3
    ) TO 's3://mybucket' with (
        format = 'ORC',
        partitioned_by = ARRAY [ 'start_month',
        'start_day' ]
    )
```

The error that I'm getting is `GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Multiple entries with same key: expr=expr and expr=expr` 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that occurs when you have 2 columns with the exact same hardcoded value, in this case both the day and month have '11' as their value.

I found a workaround but just casting their types to matching types that would later still match, like so:

```
cast('11' as varchar) as start_month,
cast('11' as char(2)) as start_day
```

If you were using them as numbers and not string it would be easier as you can use `int` and `integer` instead.